# Как мне подключить IP для mongoDB правильно и если ты находишься в России?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Как мне подключить IP для mongoDB правильно и если ты находишься в России? Я имею ввиду, что я сижу на VPN, так как MongoDB не работает в России. Я одного не пойму, если у меня постоянно меняется IP из-за VPN, то как мне это сделать правильно. Ответьте максимально быстро, прошу! Добавляю через библиотеку mongoose. Вопрос для знатоков легче легкого

Пробовал отключить впн и узнать правильный IP, вроде добавил, но всё равно что-то про IP выводит...MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/